# How to restrict the number of products in a collection and modify search filters accordingly?

Tags: catalog, overrides

UPDATE: this is partially answered(for someone who comes here lately).The answers does not updated the search filters.

I want to limit my product collection in any category/subcategory landing page with the help of a url parameter say `itemlimit=10`

I tried to do this in my phtml with `setPageSize(3)` but this is setting the number of product in a page so the filters wont get modified accordingly.

Then i tried to do it with

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit(10);
```

and getting an error like this

```
Unrecognized method 'setCurPage()'
```

Am I doing the wrong thing? Should I override the catalog resource model collection for this?

EDIT:

This is my custom block class

```
class Ziva_Customcatalog_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function _getProductCollection() {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        return $collection->getSelect()->limit(10); // This will first 10 results    
    }
}
```

EDIT as asked:
the entire trace

```
#0 C:\wamp\www\magento2\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php(225): Zend_Db_Select->__call('setCurPage', Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento2\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php(225): Varien_Db_Select->setCurPage(1)
#2 C:\wamp\www\magento2\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php(158): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar->setCollection(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#3 C:\wamp\www\magento2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#4 C:\wamp\www\magento2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
```

..................................................
    #27 C:\wamp\www\magento2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #28 C:\wamp\www\magento2\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #29 C:\wamp\www\magento2\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #30 {main}

Comment: Did you find solution of this error? I am also stuck with same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : Updated answer

config.xml

```
<config>
 . . . . . 
<global>  
        <blocks>
            <home>
                <class>Test_Home_Block</class>
            </home>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list>Test_Home_Block_Product_List</product_list>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks> 
 . . . . . .
</global>
 . . . . . 
</config>
```

~\app\code\local\Test\Home\Block\Product\List.php

```
<?php
class Test_Home_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
     protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = parent::_getProductCollection(); 
        $noOfItems = 5; // The number of items which you want to show.
        $count = 0;
        $myProductCollection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
        foreach($collection as $product)
        {
            if($count < $noOfItems) {
                $myProductCollection->addItem($product);
                $count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        return $myProductCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: This i already tried , please see my question. I have posted the error also there in question

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice it. Can you put the entire error message here?

Comment: edited my qustion

Comment: Edited the answer as well.

Comment: I tried you updated answer. but i am getting this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function setCurPage() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento2\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php on line 225`

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer, Check it

Comment: The filters are remaining the same, but it is restricting the products to given count as well as the pagination also updated

Comment: any idea how to update the filters accordingly..

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to filter `category_view` you could listen to the event which is triggered just before the collection gets loaded.
In your `config.xml`s `global` section:

```
<events>
    <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
        <observers>
            <ziva_customcatalog_catalog_block_product_list_collection>
                <class>ziva_customcatalog/observer</class>
                <method>catalogBlockProductListCollection</method>
            </ziva_customcatalog_catalog_block_product_list_collection>
        </observers>
    </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
</events>
```

In your `Observer` model you can alter the collection:

```
/**
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Ziva_Customcatalog_Model_Observer
 */
public function catalogBlockProductListCollection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    if($collection) {
        //todo: get params from request
        $collection->getSelect()->limit(10);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

The event gets dispatched in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php:161`.

Comment: I tried this code But there is no change in the output. it loads the total number of items in a collection. I tried an `echo` inside the function `catalogBlockProductListCollection` but that is not output to the browser. So i assume it is not calling this method. Any suggestions.

Comment: My observer.php is in Model/Observer.php

Comment: Your section `models` might be called different then `ziva_customcatalog`.
Take care to clear the config cache after assuring your module is enabled via `app/etc/modules` and the observers is referenced correctly according to:

 <class>ziva_customcatalog/observer</class>

Comment: this is the error i am getting `Warning: include(Mage\Ziva\Customcatalog\Model\Observer.php)`

Comment: Please show how you reference your models within `config.xml`s global section?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/module_config.xml#xml_structure2

Comment: I changed in my config.xml `<class>ziva_customcatalog_model_observer</class>` and now the method `catalogBlockProductListCollection` is getting called. But it is not limiting the product count

Comment: Now the observer is getting called, but the collection is not getting modified. any possible reasons?

Comment: Observer method is getting called, but the collection remains the same in display. any idea what is going wrong..

Comment: @zamil Did you put the listener in the **global** section?
The event gets called twice, once in _frontend_ and once in _global_. Only the second one worked for me.
Take care the collection was not loaded before.

Comment: I have put that in global section and it is getting called one time. but the collection is remaining same. and what does this `Take care the collection was not loaded before` mean